# Call a custom indicator in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am working on an indicator that require bot on chart and in the bottom window indicators. I am unable to make overlay true and false in one custom indicator script. So I want to make 2 files one contain indicators with overlay true and one with false. Now I want to know how can I call one indicator script into other so that both scripts run by using one indicator script.

Comment: https://kodify.net/tradingview/inputs/code-input-apply-indicator/ here is how you can use an indicator within an indicator I'm pretty sure you can separate the plots into top and bottom pane this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible.

Let's say `Script A` is the one with `overlay=true` and `Script B` is with `overlay=false`.

Copy everything from B to A (except the plots etc.) and use it as one indicator. So, you can still change the settings of B and see the results.

Add B to your chart also so you can visualize what's going with B. Remember to sync it's settings when you change something related to B in your main script A.